# Getting 'unable to find key' error when sending transaction in eosjs

Tags: transactions

Here is transfer: `eos.transfer("dylan1", "dylan2", "1 EOS", "", {broadcast: true, sign: true}).then(result=>{console.log(result)});`

Here is error: error: `{"code":10,"name":"assert_exception","what":"Assert Exception","details":[{"message":"condition: assertion failed: unable to find key","file":"wasm_interface.cpp","line_number":910,"method":"eosio_assert"}`

Im using latest version (dawn4)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong/how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try `1.0000 EOS`. The precision must match and EOS has 4 decimals as default. Also make sure your accounts exists.